# Android WebView .loadData Trims the text

Tags: android, webview, loaddata

I insert the code of the page in WebView, but its code is cut off.
[image: Problem and structure]

Both elements are at the bottom

`String html = readFile("index.html"); webWiev.loadData(html, "text/plane; charset=utf-8", "utf-8"); T.setText(html); //EditText T =  findViewById(R.id.editTextTextMultiLine);`

Both elements get information from the same html variable

The page was broken so I rendered it as code, that's how I discovered the problem. ("text/plane; )

The code contains all the necessary script style pages, a total of 3496 strips, and 96,501 characters.

What could be the problem? I did not find it on the Internet. Maybe some webView limit.

The Android application must download the web application from the server or, if there is no connection, from a file. Accordingly, the page is displayed incorrectly when loaded from a file, I specify the entire web application with styles and scripts in one file. Everything I did was aimed at identifying the problem. And when I found it, I started looking for it on the Internet, but I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 2):

`loadData` may truncate the text at certain length because uses a fixed-size buffer. You can use `loadDataWithBaseURL` instead and just set url parameter to null:

```
webWiev.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, html, "text/plane; charset=utf-8", "utf-8", null);
```